# what test is suitble to predict seen and unseen data

Tags: machine-learning, mean, prediction, accuracy

In my model, I want to predict both seen and unseen data and get the result that maximizes the accuracy. The problem is that in some cases seen data are  well predicted since the model is overfitting, while unseen data are not. Choosing the mean of two accuricies is not suitble as well since the variance could be large. What should i choose?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to predict on seen data? You already have the correct labels. Just trying to understand what you are asking..

Comment: I want to test the capability of slected features in predicting seen data, since at a certain threshold of features the model overfits but when applying a feature selection method unseen data are almost properly predicted and seen data are not all truly predicted. Now, if i compute the accuracy of both, the best result could be related to the seen data which are more numerous than unseen and hence based on this result due to overfitting the selected features considered to be predictive are not.

Comment: OK, why do you feel you need to somehow combine these metrics? What are you trying to optimize for? If you only care about your model's performance on unseen (future) data, you should only care about optimizing the performance on unseen data.